# DISTINCT is returning duplicate rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I am not a SQL pro. I used all columns in my SELECT statement and used them all in GROUP BY too. However, I was getting duplicate records. Then I added DISTINCT to my query but still I am getting duplicate records. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        action_by_id
       ,a.status_cd
       ,owner_dsply_nm                      AS "CASE OWNER"
       ,case_intrl_id                       AS "CASE ID"
       ,status_nm                           AS "STATUS VALUE"
       ,action_ts                           AS "STATUS CHANGE DATE"
       ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IYYY') AS "STATUS CHANGE YEAR" 
       ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IW')   AS "STATUS CHANGE WEEK" 
FROM   kdd_case_actions a 
       join kdd_status  s 
         ON a.status_cd = s.status_cd 
       join kdd_review_owner r
         ON r.owner_seq_id = a.action_by_id
WHERE  a.status_cd NOT IN ( 'SBTMNEW', 'NW', 'SB01NEW' ) 
GROUP  BY To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IYYY') 
          ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IW') 
          ,action_ts
          ,case_intrl_id 
          ,status_nm
          ,owner_dsply_nm
          ,action_by_id
          ,a.status_cd
```

[image: Results]

Comment: You don't need both `group by` and `distinct`.  In general only use `group by` when using `aggregate` functions.  With that said, could you have whitespace in any of your fields like trailing spaces?  Possibly try with `trim`.

Comment: Not sure if you refered to these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868745/oracle-sql-select-distinct-not-removing-duplicates 

and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015408/select-distinct-returns-duplicates

Comment: On a sidenote: `DISTINCT` is something rarely needed. Can you explain why there are duplicates in your results that you must get rid of? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with the query? Which tables do the columns belong to? `action_by_id` for instance; does it reside in `kdd_case_actions`, `kdd_status` or `kdd_review_owner`?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. Group By was not really needed here. I was trying to prepare a report to return cases worked by a user every week.

Comment: On a sidenote again: When dealing with multiple tables, you should always qualify the columns, e.g. `r.action_by_id` instead of `action_by_id`. This is for readability and also for stability (for the case you add columns later to your tables).

Comment: To explain what occurred: `DISTINCT` does remove duplicate *rows* from the output of the query. Date columns, however, include the time value to the nearest second. If two rows have different timestamps, they will not be removed by DISTINCT. However, when displaying the results, your tool will use the default date format to display them, which is why you can't see the different time values for `action_ts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not aggregation function in your query so why are using group  by  .. use  only distinct
and be sure that you  get only the date parte for action_ts and last be sure you have proper trimmed string for space  or not visible char

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            action_by_id
           ,trim(a.status_cd)
           ,trim(owner_dsply_nm)                      AS "CASE OWNER"
           ,case_intrl_id                       AS "CASE ID"
           ,trim(status_nm )                         AS "STATUS VALUE"
           ,to_char(action_ts, 'DD.MON.YYYY')    AS "STATUS CHANGE DATE"
           ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IYYY') AS "STATUS CHANGE YEAR" 
           ,To_char(action_ts - 7 / 24, 'IW')   AS "STATUS CHANGE WEEK" 
    FROM   kdd_case_actions a 
    join kdd_status  s ON a.status_cd = s.status_cd 
    join kdd_review_owner r ON r.owner_seq_id = a.action_by_id
    WHERE  a.status_cd NOT IN ( 'SBTMNEW', 'NW', 'SB01NEW' ) 


    TO_DATE (action_ts, 'DD.MON.YYYY')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right, I do not need Group By. The ACTION_TS column was of type DATE and not a timestamp still selecting it was returning duplicate rows. Using TO_DATE (action_ts, 'DD.MON.YYYY') solved my issue.

Comment: @Reeya Oberoi: You mean `TO_CHAR`. You wouldn't invoke `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` column.

Answer (score 2):

If your action_ts column is a timestamp or a date your only seeing a part of it in your user interface.
I guess you will see that the rows have different values on that column if you print it out more detailed.

Comment: You are right. ACTION_TS was a date column. Do you the command to print the detailed value?

Comment: Found it! Thank you so much!  TO_CHAR(ACTION_TS, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')